# Entity Framework materializing nvarchar data takes a long time

Tags: entity-framework

I have  a linq query for loading Address data from Database. (This is part of a bigger linq statement).
One of the select fields has,

```
    select new GridDetail
      {
        .......
        LocationAddress = p.Location.Address.Address1 + " " +        p.Location.Address.Address2 + ", " + p.Location.Address.City + ", " + p.Location.Address.StateProvince.Name,
        .............
      };
```

The generated query runs in about 100ms (as per SQLProfiler). But `query.ToList()` statment takes 4 seconds to execute.

I tried removing fields one by one in select statment, and realized that when i comment out the above statment, the Query executes in less than 1 sec.

The generated SQL is **not** loading the data in  N+1 fashion. All the data are retrieved in a single shot.  Each of the field in the `LocationAddress` statment maps to **`nvarchar(250)`** 
Moreover as per the `StopWatch` timings of .Net and SQLProfiler's query timing, there is **no delay in the Query Generation** from LINQ

The execution time of`.ToList()` (with `LocationAddress` in select statment) for 1 record is 3 sec, and for 3000+ records is 4 sec. This makes me think it is independent of no. of rows, so eliminated Paging as a solution.

Experts out there, could you please help me to load these data faster?

Thanks in advance  :)

**Edit :**

As per @raderick's comment, moved the concatenation part from Query to C# and the speed jumped down from 3sec to 1.5 sec.

Now the "`LocationAddress`" less query runs in 800ms against with-`LocationAddress` running in 1.5 sec...  (Note that this is for 3000 records.. For 1 record, the query runs in 1.2 sec)

Comment: You probably have to load data without concatenation and do concatenation after your `ToList()` retrieved the data. Materialization is very hard to control, so if you can you have to get rid of complex materialization and use projection for loading data before transforming it to desired object.

Comment: @raderick : Great!..  That has brought the time down from 3sec to 1.5 sec.. But still the Address-Less query runs in .8 second..

Comment: @raderick hope you can put that as an answer no ?  which is great find :)

Comment: @Raghav can you make a minimal code to reproduce the issue? I created a small test application with 4 tables and query fetching them all with materialization including string concatenation, and after first launch query is super fast. We might be missing something here.

Comment: @Sampath I have a feeling that this is not the biggest case for optimization here, and will wait OP for some more info, simple test application did not confirm this issue, might be something else we're looking for here. I will post an answer as soon as we do all possible :)